# HTML5 detect a click on a moving circle element

Tags: javascript, html

Right now I have a circle that goes from the bottom to the top of a canvas.
I attached a click event to the canvas and it console logs the coordinates of the click.

The ball also console logs the coordinates of where it is.

How can I add a circle element to 'elements' and how do I compare the canvas click event to the circle diameters coordinates.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ballRadius = 10;
var x = canvas.width/6;
var y = canvas.height-30;
var dx = 0;
var dy = -2;
   

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var x = event.pageX - elemLeft;
    var y = event.pageY - elemTop;

    console.log("CLICKED: (x,y) ", x, y);

    elements.forEach(function(element) {
        if (y > canvas.y && y < canvas.y + canvas.ballRadius && x > canvas.x && x < canvas.x + canvas.ballRadius) {
            alert('clicked an element');
        }
    });

}, false);




function drawBall() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, ballRadius, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
}

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    drawBall();

    console.log("Ball moving: (x,y) ", x, ", ", y)
    
    if(x + dx > canvas.width-ballRadius || x + dx < ballRadius) {
        dx = -dx;
    }
    if(y + dy > canvas.height-ballRadius || y + dy < ballRadius) {
        dy = -dy;
    }
    
    x += dx;
    y += dy;
}

setInterval(draw, 100);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aL9amevj/

Comment: Redrawing: You have to clear the canvas and redraw it each frame. Look into `ctx.clearRect()` for clearing and `requestAnimationFrame()` for redrawing

Comment: Click: Attach a click handler to your canvas, and from the click event grab the X and Y coordinates of the click and check to see if its 1) clicked inside of the circle and 2) the ball is below first half of the screen

Comment: You can't add a click event to a draw circle on the canvas like you would a HTML element, you will need to attach it to the canvas and find out if the mouse coordinates are within the circle. You would need to program it yourself or place a element over the canvas.

Comment: _"How do I add a click event to that circle to disappear when clicked & add a score +1 if clicked before half way going from bottom to top."_ Should circle continue to not be displayed after clicked?

Comment: @Michael _"How do you attach a click event to a canvas and get the coordinates of both the circle and the mouse?"_ That is an entirely different Question from one asked at OP?

Comment: It is the same question, I am trying to break it down to find out how to solve it. I conceptually understand what Kevin and Spencer were saying. However, I do not know how to get the diameterof a moving circles coordinates and compare the value to a click coordinate.

Comment: I added: https://jsfiddle.net/4atwqttw/ for reference

Comment: @Michael You can use an element other than `<canvas>` to retrieve `event.pageX`, `event.pageY`, see updated Answer. Note, `elemLeft`, `elemTop`, and `elements` are not defined at jsfiddle

Comment: Hey I updated the fiddle to do what I intended. My next question would be, how do I make multiple circles and keep track of each one being clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can use `css` to render a circle, `.animate()` to animate element, check if animation `animation.currentTime` is less than half of `animation.effect.computedTiming.duration / 2` `.finished` to reset element to original state.

```css
.circle {
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  left: calc(100vw - 100px);
  top: calc(100vh - 100px);
}
```

```html
<button>click</button>
<div class="circle" style="animation-fill-mode:forwards"></div>
<script>
  var score = 0;
  var button = document.querySelector("button");
  var circle = document.querySelector(".circle");
  button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
    var curr = circle.animate([{
      left: "0px",
      top: "0px"
    }], {
      duration: 10000,
      iterations: 1
    });
    circle.onclick = (e) => {
      console.log(e.pageX, e.pageY);
      var t = curr.currentTime <
        curr.effect.computedTiming.duration / 2;
      if (t) {
        score += 1;
      }
      curr.cancel();
      circle.style.display = "none";
      circle.onclick = null;
      alert((t ? "added 1 " : "did not add 1 ") 
            + "to score: " + score);
    }
    curr.finished.then(() => {
      circle.onclick = null;
      setTimeout(function() {
        button.removeAttribute("disabled");
      }, 10)
    }).catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
      button.removeAttribute("disabled");
      circle.style.display = "block";
    })
  });
</script>
```